# [slack][bolt app] how can I get scopes associated with the current request?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm working on a standard slack bolt app with nodejs and the expressreceiver as recommended by the [slack bolt guides](https://slack.dev/bolt-js/tutorial/getting-started).

One question is, how can I see the scopes associated with the current bot token?

E.g.:

- January 1 - Customer A installs with only scope [user.profile:read]
- January 10 - Our company adds a new scope required for *new* installations only, so now it is: [user.profile:read, user.profile:write]
- January 12 - Customer B installs a new app with user.profile:write

Now, in my events/action handlers, I want to know if the current request has access to user.profile:write and only then, write something to the user's profile.

I see that there is a call to "fetchInstallation" on every single slack request (I think that's part of the default authorizeFn call), but I'm not sure how I can get access to the installation object in my slack handler middleware. I'm also assuming that the installation object has scopes that the request's workspace has installed.

Note: we care about this because we want to add new permissions, but we would like to progressively migrate old customers over rather than forcing them all to re-install the app on January 10th.

Any help?

Comment: Looks like there's a discussion here: https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-js/issues/685

Answer (score 0):

The call to fetchInstallation will return an Installation object that has the info you need:

```
bot:{scopes: Array(4), token: 'xoxb-xxxxx', userId: 'xxxx', id: 'xxxx'}
0:'commands'
1:'chat:write.public'
2:'chat:write'
3:'groups:write'
length:4
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! My additional question is: where can I get this information in my listener? Or...do I need to make a manual call to fetch installation?

It seems like fetchInstallation is called for every request already, and I was wondering if I have access to that information in my listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your scopes in a listener like this

```
async function scopeTestListener({client, context, next}) {
  const { botToken } = context
  var result = await client.auth.test({token: botToken})
  console.log(result.response_metadata.scopes)
  await next();
}


app.action('some_action', scopeTestListener, async ({ action, ack, body, client, context }) => { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Though the problem with this is that I am making another network request, right? If I'm calling fetchInstallation once already, it's a bit inelegant to make another request (and also slow). Especially if I'm rushing to respond to a modal within 3 seconds, I want to reduce these calls.